# Different kind of relation in Entity Framework ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing an web application in ASP.NET MVC (Code First) and i'm new to Entity Framework, i'm having hard time understanding the relations.

I have 3 models named: Worker, Overhour and Accounting. I'm basically recording payments and salaries for employees. So, Worker can have multiple overhours (extra work time) and accounting records. Overhour should have only one worker, every overhour should have one accounting record too. Accounting should have one worker.

Here are my models (only neccesary fields):

**Worker**

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Overhour> Overhours { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accounting> Accountings { get; set; }
```

**Overhour**

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OverhourId { get; set; }
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public int PhaseId { get; set; }
    public int AccountingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }
    public virtual Phase Phase { get; set; }
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }
```

**Accounting**

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountingId { get; set; }
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public int PhaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }
    public virtual Phase Phase { get; set; }
```

Here is the thing, i don't know how to form relation between accounting and overhour. Because an overhour should have an accounting but accounting doesn't need an overhour because other controllers can create accounting too. I've been trying to solve this for like last 6-7 hours without a success. I tried many things and everytime i get some kind of error. Whats the relation type of this, for example is it one to one, one to many? Both seems weird to me.

Thanks

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Why can't it be one to one? Each overhour is to be associated with Accounting.